# how XV6 OS execute INT instruction

Tags: assembly, operating-system, system-calls, xv6

I'm studying on xv6 system call.

Below is specification about what steps does INT instruction take. (from official mit reference)
The INT instruction

```
1. decide the vector number, in this case it's the 0x40 in int 0x40.
2. fetch the interrupt descriptor for vector 0x40 from the IDT. the CPU finds it by taking the 
3. 0x40'th 8-byte entry starting at the physical address that the IDTR CPU register points to.
4. check that CPL <= DPL in the descriptor (but only if INT instruction).
5. save ESP and SS in a CPU-internal register (but only if target segment selector's PL < CPL).
6. load SS and ESP from TSS ("")
7. push user SS ("")
8. push user ESP ("")
9. push user EFLAGS
10. push user CS
11. push user EIP
12. clear some EFLAGS bits
13. set CS and EIP from IDT descriptor's segment selector and offset
```

I'm curious about stack switching from user stack to kernel stack
Below is how I understand.

1. In step no.5, store user stack's stack pointer(%ESP) to other empty register.
2. In step no.6, store kernel stack's stack pointer to %ESP. (NOW %ESP points KERNEL STACK)
3. In step no.8, **push kernel stack's stack pointer**(%ESP) to kernel stack.

But I think it should **push user stack's stack pointer** to kernel stack in step no.8
Please let me know where do I misunderstand.

Comment: Yes you are correct, but that's what step 8 specifically says as well: "push **user** ESP"

Comment: thank you for your answer. So, step 8 means that it pushes user ESP value from other internal register, not current register %ESP. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Comment: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/intn:into:int3:int1 has detailed pseudo-code.  It's a lot to wade through, but it does specify pushing "old SS and ESP", i.e. the values before `int` executed.  That's how it's possible for `iret` to restore state on return.